# Calculate at least 3 minimum and maximum numbers from array

Tags: php, arrays, max, min

Code

```
<?php

    $array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "100");
    $max = $temp = 0;
    $min = $temp = 0;

    //This loop is to get max and min value from array
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {

        if ($i == 0) {
            $max = $temp = $array[$i];
        }

        if ($i > 0) {
            if ($array[$i] > $temp) {
                $max = $array[$i];
            }
        }

        if ($i == 0) {
            $min = $temp = $array[$i];
        }

        if ($i < 0) {
            if ($array[$i] < $temp) {
                $min = $array[$i];
            }
        }

    }

    echo "Max Number = $max <br>";
    echo "Min Number = $min";


?>
```

The above code only calculates one minimum and one maximum number from the array.  I need it to calculate 3 maximum and 3 minimum numbers.

I can't use pre-made functions and can't use more than one for loop so kindly suggest me customization within the above code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "3 maximum numbers"? Do you just mean the 3 biggest numbers?

Comment: what's a "pre-made" function?  is this for a school project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks neat to me.

```
<?php

$array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "100");

$n1 = $n2 = $n3 = 1000 ;  // some high number
$m1 = $m2 = $m3 = 0 ;

//This loop is to get max and min value from array
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $x = $array[$i] ; 
    //min        
    if ($x <= $n1){
        $n3 = $n2 ;
        $n2 = $n1 ;            
        $n1 = $x ;
    } elseif ($x < $n2){
        $n3 = $n2;
        $n2 = $x;
    } elseif ($x < $n3){
        $n3 = $x;
    }

    //max
    if ($x >= $m1){
        $m3 = $m2 ;
        $m2 = $m1 ;            
        $m1 = $x ;
    } elseif ($x > $m2){
        $m3 = $m2;
        $m2 = $x;
    } elseif ($x > $m3){
        $m3 = $x;
    }        

}

echo "Min Number = $n1 $n2 $n3<br>";
echo "Max Number = $m1 $m2 $m3";


?>
```

Output:

```
Min Number = 1 2 3
Max Number = 100 8 7
```

Comment: This is awesome but one little problem count function is pre-made as i mentioned earlier i can't use count pre-made function. Is there alternative to count which is not pre-made?

Comment: Use foreach($k=>$v){.. }  $k is key $v is value

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using if statements

Checking for the max/min number works when you find another min/max value other than the previous one while looping. This is the algorithm that you use

Lets assume that your min=5
and after looping the current index value is 3, so you will have to make `min=3`

What about assigning 5 to `min2` for example?

Three variables min1, min2, min3, and nested if statements

I know it's not the best way. But have you tried this?

Comment: I think i forgot to mention that array holding numbers will be random so i can't make the program limited to already defined numbers but instead it should calculate based on any number on array and should print 3 max and 3 min numbers.

Comment: I think u didn't get me .. I didn't mean to define const numbers .. these numbers were just examples .. I meant to work the same way but to add two more variable for the `min`, and two more variables for the `max` , so when u change the value of the `max` number u put the prev. value in `max2` for example

Comment: `<?php

    $array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "100");
    $max1 = $max2 = $max3= $temp = 0;

    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  $x = $array[$i] ;
       if($x> $max1)
    {
     $max3 = $max2;
     $max2 = $max1;
     $max1 = $x;
    }
    else if ($x> $max2)
    {
     $max3 = $max2;
     $max2 = $x;
    }
     else if ($x> $max3)
  {
     
     $max3 = $x;
    } 
    }
    echo "Max Number = $max1 , $max2 , $max3 <br>";
?>`    this is an example for getting max 3 numbers for what I meant

Answer (score 0):

This code is working properly

```
<?php

    $array = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "100");

    $max1 =$max2 =$max3= -999999999999999; // highest possible number
    $min3 = $min2= $min1 = 9999999999999999; // lowest possible number

    for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $x = $array[$i] ;

        //to get the max 3 numbers
       if($x>= $max1)
       {
           $max3 = $max2;
           $max2 = $max1;
           $max1 = $x;
       }
       else if ($x> $max2)
       {
           $max3 = $max2;
           $max2 = $x;
       }
        else if ($x> $max3)
        {

           $max3 = $x;
       }
       // to get the min 3 numbers
        if($x<=$min3 && $x>$min2 )
       {
           $min3 = $x;

       }
       else if ($x<$min2 && $x>$min1)
       {
           $min3 = $min2;
           $min2 = $x;
       }
        else if ( $x<$min1)
        {
           $min3 = $min2;
           $min2 = $min1;
           $min1 = $x;
        }


    }

    echo "Max Number = $max1 , $max2 , $max3 <br>";
    echo "Min Number = $min1 , $min2 , $min3";


?>
```

The output is

```
Max Number = 100 , 8 , 7 
Min Number = 1 , 2 , 3
```

There are better ways and more efficient than that but which requires 2 loops and u don't want that !

Answer (score -1):

You just need to reverse sort the array and then slice the first three indexes. You could express it as a function:

```
function topThree(Array $arr) {
    // Sort the array in reverse
    rsort($arr); 
    // Return the first three indexes (top three)
    return array_slice($arr, 2);
}
```

See [`rsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) and [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice)

Edit: Okay this works

```
/**
 * Sorts an array of numeric values from largest to 
 * smallest and returns the three highest values.
 *
 * @param  Array  $arr  An array of numeric values.
 * @return Array  $srt  The three highest values in $arr.
 */
   function topThree(Array $arr) {
    $srt = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if(!$key) { 
            $srt[] = $val;
        } else if ($val < $srt[0]) { 
            array_unshift($srt, $val); 
        } else if ($val > $srt[count($srt)-1]) { 
            array_push($srt, $val);
        } else {
            for( $i=1; $i<count($srt); $i++) {
                if($val < $srt[$i]) {
                    array_splice( $srt, $i, 0, $val );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $max = array_slice($srt, -3, 3);
    $min = array_slice($srt, 0, 3);

    return ["min" => $min, "max" => $max];
   }


// "Test"
for($i=0; $i<20;$i++){
    $arr[]=rand(-100,100);
}

print_r($arr);
print_r(topThree($arr));
```

If `$val`'s the first `$key` `$val`'s added to `$sort`.

If `$val`'s less than `$sort[0]` `$val`'s added to the start of `$sort`.

If `$val`'s greater than `$sort[length]`, then `$val`'s added to the end of `$sort`.

Otherwise, we check every `$val` against every other `$sort` value. When we find a `$sort[$i]` value greater than `$val`, we splice the array with `$val` at `$i`.

Make sense?

Comment: Can't use pre-defined function like rsort asort and so on,

Comment: Fixed it. Surely you can use array_slice, push etc.

Comment: And if you can't even use array_splice, push, unshift what I've given you should still do the trick if you unset a matched 0, min, max value from the original array and use some recursion on the remainder (middle of sort) values.

Comment: also can only use in 1 for loop you used more than 1.

Comment: I didn't voted down someone else must have did. Thanks for helping mate :)